# Htaccess url redirect with special symbol (=) in it?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am still trying to migrate my Joomla based website to a WordPress installation. I have stumbled upon an unforseen url rewrite. Joomla uses pagination such as `article?start=3`. WordPress uses `article/3/`.

Unfortunately my attempts to rewrite "?start=3" to "/3"/ have failed. Can anyone figure out the syntax??? The = seems to break it.

edit: I will add an example of the current flow.

**1) Incomming url**

http://www.domain.com/nl/tips/160-ziggo-storing-oplossen-dns-server-aanpassen?start=2

**2) move to subdomain**

http://nl.domain.com/tips/160-ziggo-storing-oplossen-dns-server-aanpassen?start=2

**3) new title**

http://nl.domain.com/tips/ziggo-storing-oplossen-dns-server-aanpassen?start=2

**Desired url**

http://nl.domain.com/tips/160-ziggo-storing-oplossen-dns-server-aanpassen/2/

The final step is the one I am stuck at.

Current htaccess on www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nl\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(nl)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Current htaccess on nl:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
redirect 301 /uitleg/processor/91-de-processor-zoveel-cores-heeft-u-daar-iets-aan /inside/processor-uitleg/de-processor-een-processor-is-meer-dan-een-processor/
(493 lines of redirects)
```

Comment: Can You please post the htaccess here.... than i can check this out...

Comment: So you're basically checking `?start=3` in the rule itself. You're not using the `QUERY_STRING` condition.

Comment: I have added more information and the current htaccess in the question. The experiments I did with searching for "start=3" based on my limited knowledge before I posted this question were already removed because all versions I tried generated error 500.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} start=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^article$ /article/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

1. We search for `start` value in query string.
2. We check that we are on `article` page.
3. We redirect to the wordpress url and remove query parameters by adding a `?`

Those links might help you :

- [Apache wiki page on how to manipulate the Query String](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)
- [Test your apache htaccess files online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your suggestion. I think this is a good starting point but I need a bit more flexibility instead of hardcoding the word article in there (just like the examples do with the word page). This is an example url: `http://www.domain.com/nl/tips/160-ziggo-storing-oplossen-dns-server-aanpassen?start=1`. There can be different categories and also parts of that url get rewritten elsewhere in the htaccess file. Can this be done?